# Работа с датой в Си

Tags: c

Задача: вывести информацию о товаре, который был продан менее года тому. Поля структуры: продавец, название товара, цена, дата продажи.
Как правильно хранить дату?

Comment: `Как правильно хранить дату?` — в виде *timestamp*. Временная метка устойчива к переходам между летним/зимним временем и часовыми поясами.

Comment: timestamp бывают разные, unix-timestamp или `YYYYMMDDHHIISS`, например. C любым из них возможны казусы, всегда нужно понимать, как что готовить.

Comment: По условию не сказано, в каком именно виде нужно хранить дату: число.месяц.год или число-месяц-год. Подойдет ли для этих целей библиотека time.h? Если да, то как с ней правильно работать? Просто немного запутался...

Comment: @Павел, уточнить бы: где именно хранится дата и при чём тут вообще C. На postgres, например, я бы хранил в виде 'timestamp with/without time zone` (это отдельный тип в БД). Выборки уровня "год назад"  делаются элементарно, а как с этитм работать из сишного кода - уже другой вопрос. Тоже, кстати, очень простой...

Comment: Начните с [man mktime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) и обязательно почитайте SEE ALSO там.

Comment: *"Как правильно хранить дату?"* зависит от задачи (какая база данных используется (sqlite, postgres), какие операции с датой хотите проводить, насколько в вашем случае важны точность часов, часовые пояса итд).

Answer (score 0):

Как удобнее для обработки.
Я бы рассматривал как варианты в виде числа `YYYYMMDD` или [юлианский день](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0).